# Search Results XML Data returns first line of text as the result title instead of the title field for some .doc files

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

Excuse the very long title, I was just trying to be descriptive :)

I have a number of word documents stored in a document library in a document centre.  For most of the documents when I search for a term, the content that's in the "Title" field is returned in the result's title node in the Search Result XML.  However there are a number of documents that return the first line of text in the document's content as the title.  This is very peculiar bahaviour and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.  I've investigated the metadata property mappings and looked at the 'Title' property and it's retrieving the following mappings in this order:

1. Mail:5(Text)
2. People:PreferredName(Text)
3. Basic:displaytitle(Text)
4. ows_Title(Text)

As you might have guessed, these are the same as the default settings and have not been changed.  I have attempted to adjust the mappings and reorder them but nothing fixes the problem.  I don't see how any of these mappings would return the first line of text from a document when none of them detail it.

How the blazes do I get the search results to show the Title field of the documents?

This is the SPItem's XML:

```
ows_ContentTypeId="0x01010088DB89BAACA04F38A0BEE018DD0A5206009C6E9BFBC6CE4C099BF7D9D3BF986B550037DF08371674094BBD60CFE875673FD0"
ows_FileLeafRef="68;#LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_Modified_x0020_By="SHAREPOINT\system"
ows_Created_x0020_By="SHAREPOINT\system"
ows_File_x0020_Type="doc"
ows_Title="Growth Programme"
ows_NotesAndInstructions="Use this letter where we facilitate growth programme sessions"
ows_DocID="CO_GRO610"
ows_DocumentPublicationDate="2006-11-01 00:00:00"
ows_TaxCatchAll=""
ows_TaxCatchAllLabel=""
ows__dlc_DocId="DOC-2047-3109"
ows__dlc_DocIdUrl="http://server/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DOC-2047-3109, DOC-2047-3109"
ows_SectorGroup=""
ows_ServiceLine=""
ows_ID="68"
ows_ContentType="Engagement"
ows_Created="2010-08-24 11:37:19"
ows_Author="1073741823;#System Account"
ows_Modified="2010-08-25 14:03:47"
ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account"
ows__ModerationStatus="0"
ows_FileRef="68;#DocumentCentre/EngagementLetters/LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_FileDirRef="68;#DocumentCentre/EngagementLetters"
ows_Last_x0020_Modified="68;#2010-08-25 13:56:14"
ows_Created_x0020_Date="68;#2010-08-24 11:37:20"
ows_File_x0020_Size="68;#59392"
ows_FSObjType="68;#0"
ows_SortBehavior="68;#0"
ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff"
ows_CheckedOutUserId="68;#"
ows_IsCheckedoutToLocal="68;#0"
ows_UniqueId="68;#{ACE05805-6E2A-4035-A6D2-73CDF2962374}"
ows_ProgId="68;#"
ows_ScopeId="68;#{519A3EC0-039D-4F4C-A829-C9D17A9626E1}"
ows_VirusStatus="68;#59392"
ows_CheckedOutTitle="68;#"
ows__CheckinComment="68;#"
ows__EditMenuTableStart="LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows__EditMenuTableStart2="68"
ows__EditMenuTableEnd="68"
ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_LinkFilename="LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_LinkFilename2="LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_DocIcon="doc"
ows_ServerUrl="/DocumentCentre/EngagementLetters/LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_EncodedAbsUrl="http://server/DocumentCentre/EngagementLetters/LOE_CO_GRO600_310110.doc"
ows_BaseName="LOE_CO_GRO600_310110"
ows_FileSizeDisplay="59392"
ows_MetaInfo="[...]vti_cachedtitle:SR|Growth Programme&#xD;&#xA;vti_title:SR|Growth Programme[...]"
ows__Level="1"
ows__IsCurrentVersion="1"
ows_ItemChildCount="68;#0"
ows_FolderChildCount="68;#0"
ows_SelectTitle="68"
ows_SelectFilename="68"
ows_Edit="0"
ows_owshiddenversion="4"
ows__UIVersion="512"
ows__UIVersionString="1.0"
ows_Order="6800.00000000000"
ows_GUID="{77095282-3E97-4703-9249-A6E888F5ED70}"
ows_WorkflowVersion="1"
ows_ParentVersionString="68;#"
ows_ParentLeafName="68;#"
Etag="{ACE05805-6E2A-4035-A6D2-73CDF2962374},4"
ows_Combine="0"
ows_RepairDocument="0"
ows_ServerRedirected="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue when SharePoint 2010 indexes 2003 word documents (.doc).

I worked around this by using the Filename as the display property for all documents.

You have to edit the Search Results web part (I have shown my changes by  ** the changes **):

Add Filename to the fetched items:

```
<Columns> **<Column Name="Filename"/>** <Column Name="WorkId"/>  <Column Name="Rank"/>  <Column Name="Title"/>  <Column Name="Author"/>  <Column Name="Size"/>  <Column Name="Path"/>  <Column Name="Description"/>  <Column Name="Write"/>  <Column Name="SiteName"/>  <Column Name="CollapsingStatus"/>  <Column Name="HitHighlightedSummary"/>  <Column Name="HitHighlightedProperties"/>  <Column Name="ContentClass"/>  <Column Name="IsDocument"/>  <Column Name="PictureThumbnailURL"/>  <Column Name="PopularSocialTags"/>  <Column Name="PictureWidth"/>  <Column Name="PictureHeight"/>  <Column Name="DatePictureTaken"/>  <Column Name="ServerRedirectedURL"/> </Columns>
```

Then you will have to edit the XSLT to display the file name if the item is a document (make sure to **uncheck** Use Location Visualization. if you don't your changes will not take). You will have to search the xslt to find the section below. Again the items in-between the ** ** is what I added.

```
**<xsl:if test="isdocument = 'True'">
        <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="isdocument = 'False'">**
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="hithighlightedproperties/HHTitle[. != '']">
      <xsl:call-template name="HitHighlighting">
       <xsl:with-param name="hh" select="hithighlightedproperties/HHTitle" /> 
      </xsl:call-template>   
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
    **</xsl:if>**
```

Comment: Is that possible to get the "ows_EncodedAbsUrl" value through search query. Is that retrivable.?